# Facebook Login Button Integration for Sign In Android

Tags: android

trying to add a Login with facebook button example and im getting errors as below listed,

I have added the FacebookSDK library and Facebook App ID to strigs.xml file.

package com.raman.androidthirdpartyexample;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private TextView username;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);

        /*
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        */
        loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    username.setText("You are currently logged in as " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    username.setText("You are not logged in.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session opened.");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Facebook session closed.");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }
}



---------------------------------------------------

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>


----------------------------------------------------------

strings.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">FacebookApp</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="APP_ID">142459698450****</string>
    <string name="update_status">Updating status</string>

</resources>
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Menifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.facebookapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.raman.androidthirdpartyexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/APP_ID" />

    </application>

</manifest>

--------------------------------------------


Errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java
```

Answer (score 0):

hey Friend You can show this in **console** that
**android-support-v4.jar  jar mismatch**

so go to
**facebooklibrary->libs->android-support-v4.jar**

copy that jar

and **paste in your project lib folder**

and when you pase you show the dialog for the already have jar.

so you yes replace jar

and your code will be working

and if not working then

right click on jar

**click on build path -> add to build path**..

i think it helps for you

Comment: I need help on this #Dilavar , I am not able to find that option to accept your answer.Please tell that where is the option to accept an ans